# How to query the database from the VBA console?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Any way I can run a select query within the immediate console of VBA Access 2010 (VBA 7.0)?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me with a query that return integers:

```
Public Sub runQuery(ByVal query As String)

    Dim DB As DAO.Database: Set DB = CurrentDb()
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset: Set rst = DB.OpenRecordset(query)

    Do While Not rst.EOF
        Dim rowStr As String: rowStr = ""
        Dim fld As Field
        For Each fld In rst.Fields
            rowStr = rowStr & fld & "    "
        Next fld

        Debug.Print (rowStr)

        rst.MoveNext

    Loop

End Sub
```

Then call it from the immediate window:

```
runQuery "SELECT Foo, Bar FROM MyTable WHERE Foo < 42"
```